# AWS cli create-function is not executing

Tags: unix, aws-lambda

This create function command is returning nothing, not even executing. Here is my crate function command:

`aws lambda create-function --function-name simple-function --runtime python3.5 --role my-role --handler simple-function.lambda_handler --region us-east-1 --zip-file "fileb:://test-handler.zip"`

Comment: Please, provide more information regarding the result of the function and tell what went wrong.

Comment: The function does not show any result. That is the main problem here

Comment: I think it should be `python3.6`. What happens if you just type `aws`? What happens if you put incorrect information in the parameters, such as an incorrect filename?

Answer (score 0):

Remove an extra colon from zip-file value

aws lambda create-function --function-name simple-function --runtime python3.5 --role my-role --handler simple-function.lambda_handler --region us-east-1 --zip-file "fileb://test-handler.zip"

If it still not working check you have generated proper key before using [aws-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)